# How to connect Cassandra from gcloud cluster using python

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, gcloud, spark-cassandra-connector

We try to connect cluster using bash script using Jupyter notebook :

```
!gcloud compute --project "project_name" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "cassandra-abc-m"
```

After that we try to connect using :

```
import cql
con= cql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=9160,keyspace="testKS")

cur=con.cursor()
result=cur.execute("select * from TestCF")
```

How to inter-connect both?
Kindly help me for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you are SSHing out to a Google Compute (GCP) instance (running Cassandra) and are then trying to run a Python script to connect to the local node.  I see two problems in your `cql.connect` line.

First, Cassandra does not use port 9160 for CQL.  CQL uses port 9042.  I find this point confuses people so much, that **I recommend not setting** `port=` **at all**.  The driver will use the default, which should work.

Secondly, if you deployed Cassandra to a GCP instance, then you probably changed `listen_address` and `rpc_address`.  **This means Cassandra cannot bind to 127.0.0.1**.  You need to use the value defined in the yaml's `rpc_address` (or `broadcast_rpc_address`) property.

```
$ grep rpc_address cassandra.yaml
rpc_address: 10.19.17.5
```

In my case, I need to specify 10.19.17.5 if I want to connect either locally or remote.

**tl;dr;**

1. Don't specify the port.
2. Connect to your external-facing IP address, as 127.0.0.1 will never work.